# applicationDidBecomeActive method blocking my UI

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I have a method that checks the clipboard upon the app becoming active:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reload" object:nil];
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("clipboardQueue", 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        [self checkClipboard];
    });
}
```

but the app hangs for an inordinate amount of time (appears to be the Regex checking of the clipboard data) - how can I force this process to run on another thread? it seems my regular method of GCD does not appear to be working.

Here is a screenshot of my main thread while hanging:[image]

Here is the function where it hangs:

```
- (BOOL)validateUrl:(NSString *)candidate {
    NSString *urlRegEx = @"\\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\\/\\/)(?:\\S+(?::\\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\\.254(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\\.168(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\\.(?:1[6-9]|2\\d|3[0-1])(?:\\.\\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[01]\\d|22[0-3])(?:\\.(?:1?\\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\\.(?:[1-9]\\d?|1\\d\\d|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\\.(?:[a-z\\x{00a1}-\\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\\d{2,5})?(?:\\/[^\\s]*)?\\b(\\/)?";
    NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
    return [urlTest evaluateWithObject:candidate];
}
```

here is my `checkClipboard` method:

```
- (void)checkClipboard {
    [[ProfileManager sharedInstance] getUserProfile:^(BOOL done, Profile *profile, NSInteger status) {
        if (done) {
            NSURL *lastUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"clipboard"]];
            UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
            NSMutableString *urlString = pb.string.mutableCopy;

            if (urlString.length) {
                if (![urlString containsString:@"http"]) {
                    urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",urlString].mutableCopy;
                }
                BOOL urlValidate = [self validateUrl:urlString];
                if (urlValidate) {
                    if (!pb.string.length || [urlString isEqualToString:lastUrl.absoluteString] || !urlValidate) {
                        return;
                    } else {

                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                           //popup toast code

                        });
                    }
                }
            }

        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not Logged In");
        }
    }];

}
```

Comment: Try passing in `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` (`NULL`) or  `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT` instead of 0 and see if that helps.

Comment: Update your question with the `checkClipboard` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems *checkClipboard* method calls *valudateURL* in main thread, something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self valudateURL];
});
```

So if you want *valudateURL* to work in non-main thread in this case, you should just call it without dispatch_async.

-- edited --

Yes, so *getUserProfile:* block runs in main thread as you can see in screenshot, that's why it blocks the app. So if you want *validateUrl:complete:* to run in background, you should call it with dispatch_async there, something like this:

```
- (void)checkClipboard {
    [[ProfileManager sharedInstance] getUserProfile:^(BOOL done, Profile *profile, NSInteger status) {
 ...
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("clipboardQueue", 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{
        [self validateUrl:urlString complete:^(BOOL urlValidate) {
            ...
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               //popup toast code
            });
        }];
    });
 }];
}
```